# Repeated Key Value pair in Json object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am still new to Spring-boot and i am trying to create a customer with a list of roles. I have successfully created an entity for the roles however when i query the body of my Json object i have noticed some repetitions which i am not sure what is causing it.

Here my code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Roles", 
uniqueConstraints = 
          {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "RoleName")
        }
)
public class Roles implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long roleID;

    @NotBlank
    public String RoleName;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerNumber")
    private Customer customer;

    public Roles() {
    }

    public Roles(String RoleName) {
        this.RoleName = RoleName;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return RoleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String RoleName) {
        this.RoleName = RoleName;
    }

    public long getRoleID() {
        return roleID;
    }

}
```

The rolename is repeated as shown below when i query it in swagger :

[image]

Comment: Wild guess as I have never worked with Spring, but could it be due to having both a property `RoleName` as well as a getter/setter `roleName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename the field `RoleName` to `roleName`.

Spring uses jackson library for json serialization, and it thinks it's 2 different properties. Also pascal-case field naming is not common naming style in java.

If you need `RoleName` as key in json, not `roleName`, you could use jackson annotation:

```
@JsonProperty("RoleName")
private String roleName;
```

Comment: A reson for renaming the field will add to the quality of your answer.

Comment: The fix you mentioned worked fine however i still do not understand why roleID is also included in the Json object because its not part of the constructer.

Comment: It finds getter method getRoleID(), so it thinks roleID is property. You can exclude it if you need: just add @JsonIgnore annotation before roleID field declaration.